# Android - how to exclude a group that is two levels inside?

Tags: android, gradle

I wish to exclude a group, "com.android.support:support-fragment:25.1.0", that is two levels inside play-services-maps. Please let me know if it is possible to exclude it and if so, how. Appreciate your help.

If you could give me a general approach to such dependencies, that would be a great help.

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 -> 25.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.1.0
|    |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0
|    |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.1.0 (*)
|    |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.1.0 (*)
|    |    |              \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.1.0 (*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude nested transitive dependencies as explained in [Excluding nested transitive dependencies](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/excluding-nested-transitive-dependencies/7193).

[How do I exclude specific transitive dependencies of something I depend on?](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-exclude-specific-transitive-dependencies-of-something-i-depend-on/17991) explains how you can do it for a specific transitive dependency. Don't think you really need to explicitly declare each sub dependency so see if below works:

```
dependencies {
    def withoutSupportFragment = {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-fragment'
    }
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1", withoutSupportFragment
}
```